# Spring Boot extend existing properties class with new prefix

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wish to setup some custom datasource properties (`"app.datasource.alternate"`) in addition to the standard `DataSourceProperties` (`"spring.datasource"`).

> These 2 datasources are not competing (i.e. the `app.datasource.alternate` properties are not a replacement for the `spring.datasource` properties) and should live alongside each other in the default application properties.

I was hoping something like this would work:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.alternate")
public class AlternateDataSourceProperties extends DataSourceProperties {}
```

However when I define the property in my yaml:

```
app:
  datasource:
    alternate: 
      schema-username: TEST
```

And run my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = NONE)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({AlternateDataSourceProperties.class})
public class AlternateDataSourcePropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    // @Qualifier("alternateDataSourceProperties")
    private AlternateDataSourceProperties props;

    @Test
    public void propertiesAreInjected() {
        assertThat(props.getSchemaUsername()).isEqualTo("TEST");
    }
}
```

The program fails with an `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` when attempting to create the `datasource` bean in the `DataSourceConfiguration.Tomcat`:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: app.datasource.alternate-com.example.config.AlternateDataSourceProperties,spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties' available: \
  expected single matching bean but found 2: \
  app.datasource.alternate-com.example.config.AlternateDataSourceProperties \
  ,spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 66 more
```

I do not wish to re-write an entire properties class that already exists, I just need an additional set of properties under a different prefix. Is this possible in Spring Boot?

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.X

### UPDATE

with inspiration from @Prashant's answer I have tried creating an additional configuration file and injecting them with the following: `@PropertySource("classpath:config/alternate-ds.yml")`

```
# alternate-ds.yml
app:
  datasource:
    alternate:
      schema-username: TEST

# AlternateDataSourceProperties.java
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.alternate")
@PropertySource("classpath:config/alternate-ds.yml")
public class AlternateDataSourceProperties extends DataSourceProperties {}
```

I still get the `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` as now there still exists a competing bean resource. Is there a way to specify a bean should not be autowired?

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to do is create two DataSource beans with different names/qualifiers and manually configure them with the properties of your choice.

Comment: nearly but not precisely, I want to be able to store configuration for a different schema as a reference in my application to configure a spring-batch framework, however I do not wish to create a datasource for it. Regardless I am still interested in the general case here as this would not be my only use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Based on inspiration from @Prashant's answer I have come up with a work around. The solution is somewhat intrusive as it redefines an existing properties bean so could be dangerous, however the `@SpringBootTest` seem to be ok with this.
>
> An optimal solution for me would be to somehow declare that the custom bean should not be picked up by an autowiring, I have tried adding the `autowire = Autowire.NO` parameter to the `@Bean` annotation for the custom property set, but this still gives the `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`.

The problem is that spring doesn't know which `DataSourceProperties` to inject when it is referenced in library code due to me adding an additional instance of the `DataSourceProperties` class to the application context. The stop-gap measure I have come up with is recreating the original properties definition as a custom `@Bean` annotated with `@Primary` so there is no ambiguity with my custom `DataSourceProperties` Bean.

When I require the special datasource properties, I use `@Qualifier("alternateDataSourceProperties")` to reference the correct set.

The Configuration class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class AlternateDataSourcePropertiesConfiguration {
   @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.alternate")
    public DataSourceProperties alternateDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
}
```

And I have tested them as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = NONE, properties={"app.datasource.alternate.schema-username=TEST",
"app.datasource.alternate.username=SOMETHING"})
@ActiveProfiles("test") // there is a default test datasource configured in application-test.properties so I can test that primary configuration is unaffected. i.e. I have a H2 datasource configured here with username 'sa'
public class AlternateDataSourcePropertiesConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("alternateDataSourceProperties")
    private DataSourceProperties alternateDataSourceProperties;

    @Autowired
    private DataSourceProperties primaryDataSourceProperties;

    @Test
    public void propertiesAreInjected() {
        assertThat(alternateDataSourceProperties.getSchemaUsername()).isEqualTo("TEST");
    }

    @Test
    public void propertiesDontOverridePrimary() {
        assertThat(alternateDataSourceProperties.getUsername()).isEqualTo("SOMETHING");
        assertThat(primaryDataSourceProperties.getUsername()).isEqualTo("sa");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I would recommend. Your sample there is the same as the [one in the doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources)

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is:

```
    public class WebApplication { 
       private static final String CONFIGURATION_FILE_NAME_KEY = "spring.config.name";
       private static final String CONFIGURATION_FILE_NAME_VALUE = new StringJoiner(",")
            .add("application")
            .add("aurora_web")
            .toString();
       private static final String CONFIGURATION_FILE_NAME_PROPERTY = MessageFormat.format("{0}:{1}", CONFIGURATION_FILE_NAME_KEY, CONFIGURATION_FILE_NAME_VALUE);

       public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(WebApplication.class)
                .properties(CONFIGURATION_FILE_NAME_PROPERTY)
                .build()
                .run(args);
    }
```

Spring allows configuring property file names via `spring.config.name`. This could be used to allow a custom file name to be used in place of the default `application.[property|yml]`. You can create your own property file with overridden values for the data source configuration and Spring will pick this file for you. You can access the properties using `@Value()` or if you have overridden the default key values from spring's properties, the new ones would be picked from this file.
You can refer the [following official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Comment: Could you please explain the solution, I'm not quite sure how this addresses the question.

Comment: What if I wanted to have each of these property sets exist in the main application alongside each other? the autowiring will detect both `DataSourceProperties` beans regardless of whether the properties came from different files. thus giving the NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException.

Comment: Right, I suggest using `@Qualifier` for such use cases.

Comment: The problem with that is that the default datasource uses these properties and I do not wish to cause multiple bean definitions that override them. see updated answer.